# Best way to populate Parent-Children using LINQ

Tags: performance, linq, linq-to-dataset

I am trying to populate Parent and Children using LINQ, my code look like this:

```
var ds = myDAL.GetDataSet("mySP");
var Parent = ds.Tables[0];
var Children = ds.Tables[1];

var ParentChildren = from p in Parent.AsEnumerable()
                     select new 
                   { 
                     Id = p.Field<int>("Id"), 
                     Name = p.Field<string>("Name"), 
                     Children = 
                       ( from c in Children.AsEnumerable() 
                         where c.Field<int>("ParentId") = p.Field<int>("Id")
                         select new 
                         {
                            Id = c.Field<int>("Id"), 
                            Name = c.Field<string>("Name")
                         } 
                       )
                    };
```

I am afraid of performance issues as I assume it will run the nested query again and again so If I have 1000 Parents, nested query would run 1000 times?

Comment: It is LINQ to Objects or EF Core, or other LINQ Provider?

Comment: Linq to Dataset/Objects actually, I posted the simplified code

Comment: I still cannot understand what you have used. Add appropriate tags to question. In EF Core such query is called Eager Loading query and it has algorithm how to load such details.

Comment: I am not using EF/LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: I edited the question to provide more details of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wise to group the children by parent ID first, using ToLookup. This is an `O(n log n)` operation, and doing a lookup within that collection is an `O(1)` operation, so you can avoid the `O(n²)` complexity behavior of your current query.

```
var ds = myDAL.GetDataSet("mySP");
var Parent = ds.Tables[0];
var Children = ds.Tables[1];
var ChildrenByParentID = Children.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(
    c => c.Field<int>("ParentId")
    c => new 
         {
             Id = c.Field<int>("Id"), 
             Name = c.Field<string>("Name")
         });

var ParentChildren = from p in Parent.AsEnumerable()
                     select new 
                     { 
                       Id = p.Field<int>("Id"), 
                       Name = p.Field<string>("Name"), 
                       Children = ChildrenByParentID[p.Field<int>("Id")]
                     };
```

Comment: I am too weak with algorithms/notations, but I can imagine the improved performance because there would be less iterations; can you please help me understand the accumulative cost of ChildrenByParentID (grouping) and ChildrenByParentID[p.Field<int>("Id")]?

Comment: See [Big O Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). In essence, this should scale roughly proportionate to the number of rows you're processing, whereas your initial approach would explode in the amount of time it takes as you increase the number of rows.

Comment: @GertArnold: Good catch: I forgot the `.AsEnumerable()`.